# Routing requests from internal network to local Apache – a dnsmasq Job?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04, dnsmasq

Hey folks from serverfault, new to this network site.

I have a question regarding the configuration of a new server. *Ubuntu 16.04* and *Apache 2.4* will be running on the server.

We would like to allow external access to the server, which could be done with wildcard subdomains, so that `http://testsite.dev.example.com` would route to `/var/www/testsite`. I did that in another environment already with *VirtualHost* directives and I think I do know how it works.

**But:** How can I avoid that requesting `http://testsite.dev.example.com` from the internal network will be handled over the internet? I would like to avoid a speed loss when developing.

Can `dnsmasq` be used to recognize the `*.dev.example.com` pattern and handle the request internally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: read up on the feature named split-dns.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS

Additionally i doubt you own "ourdomain.com" so please use the proper domains for such a case like example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

You want to use the [-A/address](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/dnsmasq.8.html) option in the dnsmasq config:

> `address=/<domain>/[domain/][<ipaddr>]`

or in your case

> `address=/dev.ourdomain.com/<ipaddr of webserver>`

You could also use `-A address=/domain/ip`, if you rather want command line options.

Comment: D’oh! Thanks, this is simple. `dnsmasq` will know that `<ipaddr of webserver>` equals its own IP and now outgoing connection will happen?

Comment: Exactly. You could also add annoying hosts, for example /doubleclick,net/127.0.0.1 to not even resolv banners/ads to their real IP.